# D3.js How to create just 1 element that is binded to a dataset of multiple data items

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a data set with 5 objects. I'm creating an SVG for EACH of the objects because they need their own svg canvas since I'm drawing a progress completion circle for each of the objects. I need to be able to bind my text elements to my data, however instead of creating 5 text elements for each object, I only want to create 1 text element and set the text field to return the proper index.

How do I have D3 only draw 1 element (but still be binded to my data) instead of drawing 1 element for each object. Code is below:

```
// Create svg for every data item
    var svg = slideContainer.selectAll("svg").data(data);
    svg.enter()
        .append("svg")
        .attr({
            "data-id": function (d, i) { return i; },
            "class": svgClass
        });
    svg.exit().remove();

    var text = svg.selectAll("text").data(data, function (d) { return d.Margin; });
    text.enter()
        .append("text")
            .attr({
                "data-id": function (d, i) { return i; }
            })
        .text(function (d) {
            return data[$(this).attr("data-id")].Margin;
        });
    text.exit().remove();
    text.transition().duration(750)
                        .attr({
                            "x": 100,
                            "y": 100,
                            "fill": "white",
                            "class": function (d) {
                                if ($(this).attr("data-id") != $(this).parent().attr("data-id")) {
                                    return "hide";
                                }
                            },
                            "id": "text"
                        })
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.Margin;
                        });
```

Comment: D3 works by appending elements to each data element you have. So if you have multiple data elements D3 will create multiple text elements. Its unclear what you want to happen but if you only want one text element just pass '[1]' to the data before appending the text

Comment: @thatOneGuy Is [1] specifying the index?

Comment: Yeah dont do that, thats just saying you one piece of data of value '1'. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @thatOneGuy Tough to explain..Like I said above, I have an array of 5 objects. I'm creating a separate svg for each object because each object needs it's own progress bar (which is what I'm making). I create a text element and bind it to my dataset, but it creates a text element for each data object (which d3 is suppose to do). What I want to do is just create 1 text element and bind it to a certain index of that array.

Comment: Just append the text to the svg you create. Ill add an example

Comment: @thatOneGuy There's one issue with this solution. I have an "update" function called every 10 seconds. I can't get the .exit().remove() to work properly. On every update, it just re-appends a new text element to the parent.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: @thatOneGuy I feel like that's the right path, but it still isn't removing like it's suppose to. If I add the .enter() statement to the end of the svgContainer line like you have it, it doesn't let me use .exit(). However, if I add the .enter() statement then follow it by the .append("svg") method, it will let me .exit() but it still doesn't remove the previous ones before adding new elements.

Comment: https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.p7otmrdbw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is close. You just need a container and append your svg to your container like so :

```
 var svgContainer = slideContainer.selectAll("svg").data(data).enter();

 var progressBar = svgContainer.append("svg")
        .attr({
            "data-id": function (d, i) { return i; },
            "class": svgClass
        });


var progressBarText = svgContainer
        .append("text")
        //and so on

svgContainer.exit().remove();
```

Edit

Unless you want to append it to your progress bars svg :

```
var progressBarText = progressBar.append('g')
            .append("text")
            //and so on. This will use the same data as the progress bar
```